# .Net AutoCAD add customer attributes

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autocad-plugin

Below is command result:  command -->  `(entget(car(entsel))(list "*"))`

> `((-1 . <xx: 7ffffb14000>) (0 . "LWPOLYLINE") (330 . <xx: 7ffffb06a30>) (5 . "5968") (100 . "AcDbEntity") (67 . 0) (410 . "Model") (8 . "LayerName") (6 . "Continuous") (100 . "AcDbPolyline") (90 . 2) (70 . 0) (43 . 0.0) (38 . 0.0) (39 . 0.0) (10 10035.5 13933.3) (40 . 0.0) (41 . 0.0) (42 . 0.0) (91 . 0) (10 9323.13 14915.2) (40 . 0.0) (41 . 0.0) (42 . 0.0) (91 . 0) (210 0.0 0.0 1.0) (-3 ("CLEAR_WIRE" (1000 . "CWIRE") (1000 . "0") (1000 . "1") (1000 . "")) ("Wire Index" (1071 . 1))))`

In my code `PolyLineObject`, I not saw "Wire Index".
If I want add "Wire Index", how can I do?

```cs
using (BlockTable BlockList = OperateTransaction.GetObject(ActiveDatabase.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable)
{
    foreach (ObjectId BlockId in BlockList)
    {
      BlockRecord = OperateTransaction.GetObject(BlockId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTableRecord;
      foreach (ObjectId BlockRecordId in BlockRecord)
      {          
        if (BlockRecordId.ObjectClass.DxfName.Equals("LWPOLYLINE"))
        {
          PolylineObject = OperateTransaction.GetObject(BlockRecordId, OpenMode.ForRead) as Polyline;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "attributes" are called XData which means Extended Data. 
Example of using this by .net You can find for example [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-NET/files/GUID-92D663FA-0452-44F4-BDAC-0EEF0AF3BD88-htm.html).